# Mongoose updateMany, but each one with different value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a collection where I put all the users, it has fields like id, name, password, balance, etc. Then in code, I have an array with ids and balance changes. What I want to do is to update balance of all these users with these ids by the amount given in the array.

For example:

Three documents in database:

```
1. id: 1,
   name: John,
   balance: 0
2. id: 2,
   name: Alice,
   balance: 100
3. id: 3,
   name: Alex,
   balance: 1000
```

Array:

```
[
  {id: 1, balanceChange: 150},
  {id: 3, balanceChange: -500}
]
```

Would result in John having balance of 150 and Alex 500. I thought about async series and findOneAndUpdate, but I don't know if so many requests are not too heavy. Maybe it is possible to do it in one? Pass an array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite). You can use native driver methods on your mongoose models via `.collection`. i.e `Model.collection.bulkWrite(updates)`. Where `updates` is an array of `"updateOne"` documents. Many answers here showing usage of `.bulkWrite()`.

Comment: I've found only one with findOneAndUpdate, maybe used wrong phrase to search. Thank you for your answer, will take a look at it. Thanks!